# QT Resize border thickness for QDockWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I'm working on a dockable widget using QDockWidget.
It all works so far but the problem is that when I undock it and want to resize it by grabbing the window edge with the mouse, the border where I can resize it seems to be about 1pixel thick, making it very fiddly to try to grab.
Is there any way of specifying a thicker resize border so that the users don't have to re-try 7 times to try to grab it?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question.  When a `QDockWidget` is undocked it becomes a top level window.  That being the case any 'decorations' that allow it to be resized are usually under the control of the window manager rather than the application itself.  You might also want to have a look at [`QSizeGrip`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsizegrip.html).